# How to render table with Redcarpet and Markdown

Tags: markdown, redcarpet

I'm trying to render a table like this with Redcarpet

```
| header 1 | header 2 |
| -------- | -------- |
| cell 1   | cell 2   |
| cell 3   | cell 4   |
```

but it's not working.

Is it possible to render a table with Redcarpet ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can render a table like that, but you have to enable the `:tables` option.

```
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :tables => true)

text = <<END
| header 1 | header 2 |
| -------- | -------- |
| cell 1   | cell 2   |
| cell 3   | cell 4   |
END

puts markdown.render(text)
```

Outputs:

```
<table><thead>
<tr>
<th>header 1</th>
<th>header 2</th>
</tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell 1</td>
<td>cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell 3</td>
<td>cell 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Do you know how to set this option for `haml` helper? I tried `set :markdown, :tables => true`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Alexey: did you find a way to activate it for HAML?

Comment: @Alexey see my response (if it doesn't get deleted by moderators)

Comment: Do not use spaces in `|------|------|`

Comment: Is it possible to render table without header?

`
| cell 1   | cell 2   |
| cell 3   | cell 4   |
`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer for table format is great. Trying to add this as a comment loses formatting. Yet adding it as an answer is somewhat questionable as well.

Anyway... this is in response to the question about using markdown table option with haml (in the context of Rails).

application_helper.rb

```
  def markdown(content)
    return '' unless content.present?
    @options ||= {
        autolink: true,
        space_after_headers: true,
        fenced_code_blocks: true,
        underline: true,
        highlight: true,
        footnotes: true,
        tables: true,
        link_attributes: {rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank"}
    }
    @markdown ||= Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, @options)
    @markdown.render(content).html_safe
  end
```

Then in a view (views/product_lines/show.html.haml):

```
= markdown(product_line.description)
```