# Table not render when use Redcarpet in Jekyll GitHub Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, redcarpet

As of `maruku` engine (the default), writing table like

```
surround text, etc.

| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |

surround text...
```

would render correctly.

But when I switch to `redcarpet` (add `markdown: redcarpet` into `_config.yml`), the table no longer rendered, both localhost and on GitHub Pages.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: no, that topic is not relate to jekyll, but it does gives me some hint.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Adding only `markdown: redcarpet` into `_config.yml` is not enough, It's also need the `extensions` part, e.g.

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables", "with_toc_data"]
```

Comment: from the Jekyll documentation: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#redcarpet 
And theese are the **Redcarpet extensions**, from the Readme : http://git.io/Xk0CQQ

Answer (score 6):

For this question, it seems the important extension here is "tables".

However if you want more Github flavored markdown, there are a few more listed at http://sholsinger.com/2014/03/jekyll-github-flavored-markdown.

Combining with neizod's answer I ended up using.

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables", "strikethrough", "superscript", "with_toc_data"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `redcarpet` markdown engine is no longer supported by GitHub Pages and may cease working at any time.

A very straightforward solution is to delete the `markdown` setting in site's `_config.yml` file and instead have an extra line between the headline/text and the table.

You can get more information from [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-your-markdown-processor-to-kramdown/) and this solution was taken from this [issue](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/123).

Answer (score 0):

[How to render table with Redcarpet and Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296453/how-to-render-table-with-redcarpet-and-markdown)

Also, I can confirm
[Kramdown](http://github.com/gettalong/kramdown)
will do this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still running into this years later here's an example of how to fix it.

If your markdown is like this:

```
# My Favorite Books 
| Title | Description |
| ----- | ----------- |
| Attack Surface | A sci-fi book by Cory Doctorow showing how currently available tech can be used to oppress |
```

It will render fine on github.org but fail to render on github pages.

The solution is to ass a blank line above you table like so:

```
# My Favorite Books 

| Title | Description |
| ----- | ----------- |
| Attack Surface | A sci-fi book by Cory Doctorow showing how currently available tech can be used to oppress |
```

Thanks to LTChen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753208/620699) for putting me on the right track.