# How to use Markdown tables in HAML

Tags: markdown, haml

I'm trying to render a table in a `:markdown` filter in HAML.  I've checked the syntax against a cheatsheet and tried both syntaxes presented.

```
:markdown
  
  ### This is [markdown](https://devhints.io/markdown) yay!

  ------
  
  | Column 1 Heading | Column 2 Heading |
  | ---------------- | ---------------- |
  | Some content     | Other content    |
  
  ------
  
  Column 1 Heading | Column 2 Heading
  --- | ---
  Some content | Other content
```

Here's the result.  The first line and the horizontal rules are just to confirm that the contents *are* in fact being translated into Markdown—except for the thing I really care about, the table.

[image: example of failed Markdown in HAML]

What am I doing wrong?  Why is this not working?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296453/how-to-render-table-with-redcarpet-and-markdown) help you?

Comment: @Skin_phil: it does _help_ (reminding me that tables are not in the main spec—hard to believe based on how ubiquitous they are in Markdown these days) but it doesn't answer the question of how to make it work with HAML.

Answer (score 0):

A few key issues here are that

- even though table support is ubiquitous in Markdown these days, the original spec didn't include any support for tables, and
- HAML is content to offer the bare minimum, and
- even though underlying gems like Redcloth offer support for tables, HAML apparently offers no way to configuring the handling of Markdown

  - [There's no mention of it in the documentation about Markdown filters](https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter)
  - [A search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=HAML+markdown+configuration&t=osx&ia=web) (currently) shows this page first, and not much else that looks promising.
  - There's no mention of Markdown configuration options in [pages that list HAML configuration options](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/haml/5.0.1/Haml/Options)

So it appears that HAML doesn't really give you the ability unless you want to go to the trouble to [create your own custom filter](https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#custom-filters).